# Matched pair of locally compact groups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In measure theoretic language there is a notion of matched pair of locally compact (l.c.) groups due to Baaj-Skandalis-Vaes. A pair $(G_{1}, G_{2})$ is called a matched pair of l.c. groups if there exists a l.c. group $G$ such that, $G_{1}$, $G_{2}$ are closed subgroups of $G$, intersection of $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ is trivial inside $G$ and the complement of $G_{1}G_{2}$ is of measure zero in $G$. Does there exists any notion which replace the last condition by some topological criterion?

Comment: What do you mean by “topological”? Without using the group structure? Only regarding $G_1G_2$ as a subspace of $G$?

Comment: I think it means topological as opposed to measure-theoretic.

Comment: @MTS “of measure zero with respect to a Haar measure” only depends on the topological-group-structure. It seems to be a plausible interpretation of “topological criterion” to take this as a valid answer.

Comment: @TheUser yes, of course you're right.

Comment: I think that this "matched" criterion is somewhat inspired by Furstenberg's disjointness definition in dynamics (especially in light of MTS answer below), which has interpretation both in measure theory (Ergodic theory) and in topological dynamics (topology), although the interpretations gives you some different outcomes in each category...

Comment: You may want to look at the notion of quasi-product of Caprace-Monod: a topological group $G$ is the quasi-product of closed, normal subgroups $N_1,...,N_k$ if the multiplication map $N_1\times...\times N_k\rightarrow G$ is injective with dense image. Caprace and Monod construct examples of center-free quasi-products, some of them NOT being direct products. See Appendix II in 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.4101.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could ask that the complement of $G_1G_2$ is nowhere dense, or more generally a [meagre set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set).  But whether this notion is appropriate or not really depends on what application you have in mind.

Also, unless I am missing something, isn't every pair of locally compact groups is a matched pair?  Just take $G = G_1 \times G_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Obviously direct product provides the trivial matching. But I think nowhere dense is a good candidate for that.

Comment: Why isn’t it trivial in the context of Baaj-Skandalis-Vaes?

Comment: The point is not that this notion admits trivial cases, but that it admits highly non trivial ones. The emphasis is not on whether a given pair is a matched pair but whether a group $G$ can be reconstructed from a matched pair...

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli Yes, I wouldn't suspect Baaj-Skandalis-Vaes to come up with a trivial notion! It just seems a funny way to phrase the definition - it makes more sense if $G$ is the focus of the definition rather than $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Comment: Previously Baaj and Skandalis considered the map $(g_{1},g_{2})\to g_{1}g_{2}$ to be a homeomorphism. The Definition mentioned above was one step generalization. As per my understanding the goal was is to carry forward Drinfeld's bicrossed product construction in operator algebraic framework. General theory of Double crossed product for quantum groups in operator algebraic setting is due to Baaj-Vaes. One of the delicate parts of their construction was to give an explicit description of the $C^{*}$-algebra of the double crossed product.